# Improve atof using SIMD

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, string-conversion

I want to speedup string to float (here `long double`, extended precision IEEE 754) conversion using SIMD instructions.

`std::numeric_limits< long double >::digits10 == 18` and for practice it is enough to just read 18 significant `char`s (i.e. those starting after first non-`'0'`), make `significand` - a binary-coded decimal value from them (9-byte "integer"), calculate integer `exponent` value (power of ten, from dot position and, maybe, exponent part) and finally fuse both by `significand * 10^exponent` operation.

There are few thinkable ways for the `significand`:

1. Collect significant `char`s one by one and update 64-bit unsigned value (firstly zero-initialized) `significand = significand * 10 + (c - '0');` (it should not overcome `(std::numeric_limits< std::int64_t >::max() - nextc) / 10` (signed 64-bit is intentionally here) on each step). It can be loaded using `fild qword ptr ...` instruction. Downside is the need to use slow 64-bit integer arithmetic.
2. Collect first (at most) 18 significant `char`s into small array and fuse them into binary coded decimal form to convert them into internal x87 representation using `fbld tbyte ...` instruction. Downside is a loss of a couple of bits at the end (1E18 vs 9223372036854775807 ~= 9.2E18).

   My workable implementation (relative difference with `std::istream` results is about 5E-18):

   ```
   template< typename F >
   void read_float(F & result)
   {
       static_assert(std::is_floating_point< F >::value, "!");
       char c = *cursor;
       std::uint8_t significand[18];
       auto s = significand;
       std::int32_t after = 0;
       std::int32_t before = 0;
       char sign = c;
       switch (c) {
       case '-' :
       case '+' :
           c = *++cursor;
           break;
       default : {
           break;
       }
       }
       [&]
       {
           bool d = false;
           for (;;) {
               switch (c) {
               case '.' :
                   before = 1;
                   break;
               case '0' ... '9' : {
                   if (c != '0') {
                       d = true;
                   }
                   if (0 < before) {
                       ++before;
                   }
                   if (d) {
                       *s++ = (c - '0');
                       if (s == significand + sizeof significand) {
                           std::int32_t a = 0;
                           for (;;) {
                               switch ((c = *++cursor)) {
                               case '0' ... '9' :
                                   ++a;
                                   break;
                               case '.' : {
                                   after = a;
                                   break;
                               }
                               default : {
                                   if ((before == 0) && (after == 0)) {
                                       after = a;
                                   }
                                   return;
                               }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   break;
               }
               default : {
                   if (!d) {
                       *s++ = 0;
                   }
                   return;
               }
               }
               c = *++cursor;
           }
       }();
       if (0 < before) {
           after -= (before - 1);
       }
       std::uint32_t exponent = 0;
       switch (c) {
       case 'e' :
       case 'E' : {
           c = *++cursor;
           char esign = c;
           switch (c) {
           case '-' :
           case '+' :
               c = *++cursor;
               break;
           }
           [&]
           {
               for (;;) {
                   switch (c) {
                   case '0' ... '9' :
                       exponent = (exponent << 3) + (exponent << 1) + (c - '0');
                       break;
                   default : {
                       return;
                   }
                   }
                   c = *++cursor;
               }
           }();
           if (esign == '-') {
               after -= exponent;
           } else {
               after += exponent;
           }
           break;
       }
       default : {
           break;
       }
       }

       alignas(32) std::uint8_t bcd[10] = {};
       std::uint32_t b = 0;
       do {
           --s;
           if ((b % 2) == 0) {
               bcd[b / 2] = *s;
           } else {
               bcd[b / 2] |= (*s << 4);
           }
           ++b;
       } while (s != significand);

       if (sign == '-') {
           bcd[9] = (1 << 7);
       }

       asm(
       "fldl2t\n"
       "fildl %[exp10]\n"
       "fmulp\n"
       "fld %%st\n"
       "frndint\n"
       "fxch\n"
       "fsub %%st(1), %%st\n"
       "f2xm1\n"
       "fld1\n"
       "faddp\n"
       "fscale\n"
       "fstp %%st(1)\n"
       "fbld %[tbyte]\n"
       "fmulp\n"
       : "=t"(result)
       : [exp10]"m"(after), [tbyte]"m"(bcd)
       : "memory", "st(1)", "st(2)"
       );
   }
   ```

   Really exponentiation (`f2xm1`, `fscale`) can be avoided using about ~9.8k length lookup table for `long double` precalculated powers of ten (15 bit exponent for extended precision), but advantage of its using is discussable.
3. Read 8-byte chunks of significant bytes and apply bit manipulations to them. Then assemble them into BCD as in previous way. Downside is 64-bit integer arithmetic, but maybe it better, then bytewise loop in above case.

   ```
   std::uint32_t atoi(const char s[])
   {
       using c8 = char [8];
       static c8 z = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
       auto string = reinterpret_cast< const std::uint64_t & >(*s) - reinterpret_cast< const std::uint64_t & >(z);
       string = (((string >> 4) & 0x00F000F000F000F0LL) | (string & 0x000F000F000F000FLL));
       c8 & c = reinterpret_cast< c8 & >(string);
       c[1] = c[2];
       c[2] = c[4];
       c[3] = c[6];
       return reinterpret_cast< const std::uint32_t & >(c);
   };
   auto bcd = atoi("01234567");
   ```

   To generate small variants of input I use the following function:

   ```
   char input[1 << 24];
   auto cursor = input;
   auto size = []
   {
       char x[] = "+1.5E+1";
       for (auto s : {"", "-", "+"}) {
           auto y = x;
           while (*s) {
               *y++ = *s++;
           }
           for (auto m : {"1", "1.", ".1", "1.1"}) {
               auto z = y;
               while (*m) {
                   *z++ = *m++;
               }
               cursor = std::copy(x, z, cursor);
               *cursor++ = ' ';
               for (auto E : {'E', 'e'}) {
                   *z = E;
                   for (auto S : {"", "-", "+"}) {
                       auto t = z + 1;
                       if (*S) {
                           *t++ = *S++;
                       }
                       *t++ = '1';
                       assert(t < x + sizeof x);
                       cursor = std::copy(x, t, cursor);
                       *cursor++ = ' ';
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return cursor - input;
   }();
   ```

Is there a way to speedup conversion from string to 64-bit integer value using SSE 4.2 or something else?

Comment: If you are trying to find the most accurate answer (i.e. the floating point number that is closest to your string) then it is most definitely not enough to read only 18 digits. All of the digits might be significant. The common algorithm to do this conversion is David Gay's. You might find this blog interesting, it describes the algorithm in great detail http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/

Comment: I want to find not too coarse (maybe double precision), but very fast atof algorithm. Thank you for the link.

Comment: The `fbld` approach is unlikely to be fast. The x87 FPU has not been a priority for CPU architects for a long time. Considering that the integer BCD instruction were outright removed in x86-64, I would not be surprised if the floating-point BCD-loading instructions were somewhat disliked by processor designers. In any case, a quick look at Agner Fog's tables suggest that no CPU available does a `fbld` in less than 40 cycles.

Comment: @EOF 40 cycles is far less then 18 * number of cicles for 64 bit multiply, add and compare with upper limit (OK, first ten of them can be performed in 32-bit field). It is strange, that there is no special hardware instruction to convert ASCII representation at least for whole numbers. How many GWh per year can be saved! It is mistake of the same level, as choosing null terminated strings instead of pascal-style ones.

Comment: Parsing of 2.5MB textual input consist of floating point values was hasten from ~450 ms (scanf("%lf");) to 26 ms using above function.

Comment: if you're allowed to change to input format then it's much better to use binary, much faster to read and write

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc With no doubt.

Comment: Until AVX512, there widest SIMD integer multiply is 32x32 => 64-bit.  (Or the mantissas of `double`).  See [How to implement atoi using SIMD?](//stackoverflow.com/q/35127060) for string to *32-bit* integer including some parsing of a terminator, using `pmaddwd` to multiply by place value.

Comment: You might want to read [how rapidjson does it](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/master/include/rapidjson/internal/strtod.h).